# Lego Mindstorms daisy chain (java)

Tags: java, wifi, lego-mindstorms

I have a problem with connecting two Lego Mindstorms bricks with daisy chain. I have a code written in java and the robot works through wifi. 
Here's the part of the code where the robot has commands with all ports. Commented part is with the second brick.

```
private RobotService() {

}

public void connectToRobot(String ip) throws RemoteException, NotBoundException, MalformedURLException {
    robot = new RemoteEV3(ip);
    left = robot.createRegulatedMotor("A", 'L');
    right = robot.createRegulatedMotor("D", 'L');
    frontWheels = robot.createRegulatedMotor("C", 'L');
    up = robot.createRegulatedMotor("B", 'L');

    //down = robot.createRegulatedMotor("B", 'L');
    //open = robot.createRegulatedMotor("4", 'L');
    //close = robot.createRegulatedMotor("4", 'L');
   // Sound.beep();
    //Sound.buzz();
}
```

Comment: and the problem is???

Comment: the problem is that the program can't see that second brick and i don't know where the problem is

Comment: `program can't see that second brick` and `Commented part is with the second brick`. you see the problem?

Comment: No no it's not about that. I commented this part just for a while, when i uncomment it it doesn't work.